# Is there anything wrong with this password reset procedure?

Tags: python, security, flask

Is there anything wrong with this procedure?

1. Enter in username and email in a reset form.
2. Flask creates a really long random string and stores it into the session under "reset_code".  Session will also have a key for "reset_pw_username"
3. Flask sends an email with a link to the path /password_reset/reset_pw_username/reset_code
4. That link displays a form where the customer can reset the password if the session reset code matches the session reset_code item. Otherwise it bombs out.
5. The session will expire the reset code after an hour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must ensure that username and email entered match one of the accounts (or use emails as username in the first place).

From a usability perspective, this won't work if the browser that displays the link contained in the email is not the same as the one initially used.

Apart from that, you should pay special attention to the randomness (not so much the length) of the reset_code. It should be cryptographically random (i.e. [`os.urandom`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.urandom)) so that an attacker cannot simply guess it. `random.random` and derived methods are not suitable.

Answer (score 4):

If I can enter a username and email address, then I can get a reset token for any user of your service emailed to me.  Maybe you should check that the email address is one that actually belongs to the user whose password is going to be reset.

Answer (score 1):

As Jean-Paul pointed out, asking for both username and e-mail requires checking whether they both match the same user. Hence it is more common to ask for **either**  username or e-mail, verifying they are in your database, and sending recovery link to appropriate address.

Storing the recovery token in session data will likely be cumbersome for some users, as phihag described. Such tokens are usually stored in regular database. Note, however, that they are *password-equivalent*: once obtained, they can be freely exchanged for a password. Because of that, they need to salted & hashed (in the same secure manner that is applied to passwords themselves) before storing in the database. This also means that your recovery handler must salt & hash the incoming token before searching for it in your database.

Comment: Well, if you're generating a long random string for your reset token then there's no point in salting it.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is use email address as username,then  user just have to remember his email address.And you just only have to validate user's email address.